# Is it possible to import a component without a module

Tags: angular, angular-aot, tree-shaking

I am wanting to import a component into another component in Angular 4.4.6. This may end up being just a theoretical answer, which is fine. Just figured I would reach out here to see if anyone is doing this. I typically would just create a module for the component etc. etc., but I am really trying to cut out any extra files - trying to avoid file smell.

I have no real code to share, although I am picturing something like this:

```
@Component({
     selector:'someSelector',
     template:`<html>some html</html>`,
     providers: [someService],
     declarations: [someComponent]  //wanting to do this but I know I can't
})
```

I do this already bring in outside components in a few places throughout the app, like parent/children communication with @ViewChild() so I get that. Just wondering if this is even possible without making the component I need access to in HTML globally available or if I have to create a module and import it like normal. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Component `declarations` and `providers` were supported in Angular 2 RC4. Angular modules were introduced in RC5 and are supposed to fully replace this functionality in modules.

> Just wondering if this is even possible without making the component I need access to in HTML globally available or if I have to create a module and import it like normal.

In order to be unavailable globally, a component/directive should be specified in module `declarations` but not `exports`. Its selector will be compiled only in components/directives that belong to same module.

Answer (score 1):

Till to `Angular 2 RC5`, you could add components into the another components `directives` property.

Starting from `Angular 2 RC5`, components *can be imported only in the modules*. I think you will not use below versions of Angular, so you must to import them into the modules.

Looking into the [**Documentation**](https://angular.io/api/core/Component) you can see that there are no declarations in the `Component` decorator

```
@Component({ 
  changeDetection?: ChangeDetectionStrategy
  viewProviders?: Provider[]
  moduleId?: string
  templateUrl?: string
  template?: string
  styleUrls?: string[]
  styles?: string[]
  animations?: any[]
  encapsulation?: ViewEncapsulation
  interpolation?: [string, string]
  entryComponents?: Array<Type<any> | any[]>
  preserveWhitespaces?: boolean
  // inherited from core/Directive
  selector?: string
  inputs?: string[]
  outputs?: string[]
  host?: {...}
  providers?: Provider[]
  exportAs?: string
  queries?: {...}
})
```